# Python asyncio: receiving broadcast UDP blocked behind Windows firewall but other python network is fine

Tags: python, python-asyncio, windows-firewall

I have the following to **receive** UDP broadcast messages which works absolutely fine on my Windows 7 laptop but does not receive anything on Windows 10. I realised the difference was firewall settings on the Windows 10 was blocking python for 'public' - once I allowed it, it was fine.

However, the rest of the code has various send/receive over the network functions that all work fine with the original firewall settings. Why is only this UDP broadcast receiving blocked?

```py
class VAM_listener_protocol:
    def __init__(self):
        self.transport = None

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        print("connected")
        self.transport = transport

    def datagram_received(self, data, addr):
        print("RECD")
        
    def error_received(self, exc):
        LOG.error(f'Error received: {exc}')

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        pass
```

Called using:

```py
loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s.bind(('',13400))  # Leaving IP blank will go to default broadcast address
transport, protocol = await loop.create_datagram_endpoint(
            lambda: VAM_listener_protocol(),
            sock=s)
```